Bot to kick members out of the server with specific roles and send a message in the bot staff records channel and the user's DM (who was kicked)
I'm currently developing a bot that can kick out members from the server based on specific roles. It's designed to send a message to the staff records channel and also notify the user via direct message about the reason for their kick. The bot will execute a double kick if a user joins and selects that role, and on the third occurrence, it will proceed to ban the member. Notifications will be sent to both the staff records channel and the user's direct messages.
So far, the code appears to be functioning correctly, successfully executing the task of kicking out members and sending messages in the staff bots channel. However, it's encountering an issue when attempting to send messages to users' direct messages, resulting in an exception indicating that it couldn't deliver the message to the specific user.
Are there any necessary fixes required in the code below to address this issue? Additionally, the bot has been granted the necessary message permissions, along with kick and ban permissions.
**Also, ensure that the user has their direct messages (DMs) open. If there's still an issue, is there anything specific I should look for or add to the code to diagnose the error?
**
Here is the code:-
main.py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()

# Import your bot token from config.py
from config import TOKEN

# Define your bot prefix
PREFIX = "!"

# Define your role ID
ROLE_ID = 1224742347816960063  # Replace with the actual role ID

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, intents=intents)

# Define the default channel ID as None
CHANNEL_ID = None
STAFF_BOTS_CHANNEL = "ㆍ┇staff-bots"  # Replace with the actual channel name

# Define a dictionary to track the number of kicks for each user
offense_count = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if ROLE_ID in [role.id for role in member.roles]:
        await member.kick(reason="Automatic kick on join - 1st Offence")
        await member.send(f"1st offence: You have been kicked from the server")

@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if ROLE_ID in [role.id for role in after.roles] and ROLE_ID not in [role.id for role in before.roles]:
        user_id = after.id
        if user_id in offense_count:
            offense_count[user_id] += 1
        else:
            offense_count[user_id] = 1

        if offense_count[user_id] >= 3:
            await after.ban(reason="3rd Offence - Automatic ban")
            if STAFF_BOTS_CHANNEL:
                staff_bots_channel = bot.get_channel(1224742349410795575)  # Use the actual channel ID
                if staff_bots_channel:
                    await staff_bots_channel.send(f"3rd offence: Banned {after.name}")
        else:
            if STAFF_BOTS_CHANNEL:
                staff_bots_channel = bot.get_channel(1224742349410795575)  # Use the actual channel ID
                if staff_bots_channel:
                    if offense_count[user_id] > 1:
                        kick_reason = f"{offense_count[user_id]}th Offence"
                    else:
                        kick_reason = "Picked role - 1st Offence"
                    await staff_bots_channel.send(f"{kick_reason}: Kicked {after.name} - Picked role")
                    await after.kick(reason=kick_reason)

@bot.command(name="setup")
async def setup(ctx, channel_id: int):
    global CHANNEL_ID
    CHANNEL_ID = 1224742349410795575  # Set CHANNEL_ID to the provided channel_id
    await ctx.send("Setup complete!")

@bot.event
async def on_member_ban(guild, user):
    if CHANNEL_ID:
        await bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID).send(f"3rd offence: Banned {user.name}")

@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    if ROLE_ID in [role.id for role in member.roles]:
        try:
            await member.send("You have been banned from the server")
        except discord.errors.Forbidden:
            print(f"Failed to send message to {member.name}: User cannot receive direct messages")

bot.run(TOKEN)


Rest there are two more file. config.py with just the token and requirements.txt thats exporting discord.py.
I need help to fix this issue. Pls, if someone who has faced this issue or knows why this could be happening can reach back!

You are not able to PM a user from your discord bot regardless of their DMs being open or not, if you don't have any servers in common. So in
on_member_join and on_member_update you can swap the order you're executing them in, allowing you to PM successfully before then kicking/banning. Unfortunately you can not achieve this with the on_member_ban and on_member_remove events
